# how do i create a namespace for my class1 and then instantiate it

Tags: javascript

how would i instantiate Class1?

```
var Namespace1 = {};
Namespace1.Class1 = {
    test: function () {
        alert('test');
    }
};

var x = Namespace1;

x.Class1.test();
```

Not sure if I'm doing this right?

Comment: Are you trying to create a Class?

Comment: Can I create a class inside a namespace object?

Comment: Well JS is essentially class-less, so this gives you nested objects, it's ok enough if you don't need inheritance.

Comment: this might help: http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-class-instantiation/

Comment: Something like this I believe you are trying to do? http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/my8An/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespace: you need to defined nested object to define namespace which you are already doing.

```
Namespace1 = {};
```

Class: Since you want to define a class to be able to instantiate you need to define Class1 as function (how classes are implemented in javascript).

```
Namespace1.Class1 = function(){ };
Namespace1.Class1.prototype.test = function(){ alert("test"); };
```

Instantiate: now you can use the full name of the class with `new` to instantiate and invoke function on the object.

```
var x = Namespace1;
var obj = new x.Class1;//you could directly use Namespace1.Class1 as well
obj.test();
```

Comment: So do I just use a naming convention for the private vs public methods in my class? _private vs Public?

Comment: yes. or you can define your methods which use private variable inside constructor. `function(){ var pvtVar = ""; this.test=function(){pvtVar="abc";}; }`